# webdriver - how to print all the main links in the page

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i want to print all the main module links ...but i was getting all the links printed if take the frame and then extarct all the links using tag "a".
please correct me..

```
List All_Module_Links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-menu']"));
WebElement modules_box = All_Module_Links.get(0);
List links =modules_box.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total links are : "+links.size());

for(int i=0;i    {
System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
}![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: And whats the issue? Sorry, but I do not understand what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
     WebElement topmenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-menu']"));

     List<WebElement> links =topmenu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
     System.out.println("Total links are : "+links.size());

     for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
     {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
     }
```